# Timestamp Inconsistency

Tags: javascript, datetime, casting, timestamp

I was playing around with JavaScript dates and I'm looking for an explanation pertaining to the last logged array. Why are the numbers `1352589000, 1352589395` different?

Code

```
var examples = [
    "Fri Jan 16 1970 10:43:09 GMT-0500 (EST)",
    1352589395
];

var text = [
    new Date((examples[0])),
    new Date((examples[1])),
];

var unix = [
    new Date((examples[0])).getTime(),
    new Date((examples[1])).getTime(),
];

console.log(examples);
console.log(text);
console.log(unix);
```

Output

```
[
  'Fri Jan 16 1970 10:43:09 GMT-0500 (EST)',
  1352589395
][
  'Fri Jan 16 1970 10:43:09 GMT-0500 (EST)' ,
  'Fri Jan 16 1970 10:43:09 GMT-0500 (EST)' 
][
  1352589000,
  1352589395
]
```

Comment: +1 for "playing around with..."

Comment: It's not the problem you're having, but note that you can't count on that date string being parsed by different JavaScript engines. As of ES3, a JavaScript engine is required to parse the format it produces from `Date#toString` but no others (most engines *also* support "year/month/day" but not necessarily any variations), and the format delivered by `Date#toString` isn't dictated by the spec. In ES5, the spec added a simplified version of ISO-8601: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers are in milliseconds. The difference between them is 395, which is less than half a second. The string format you're using only goes down to the second, and so its milliseconds portion is 0, but the number you're parsing includes the milliseconds (all 395 of them).

Answer (score 1):

Because that Unix time stamp is in milliseconds.  You didn't specify milliseconds, so it is giving you exactly 10:43:09 on Jan 16, 1970.  The other time stamp is giving you 10:43:09.395 on Jan 16, 1970.

EDIT

The Unix timestamp is the number of SECONDS since the Jan 1st, 1970.  Javascript's getTime() returns the number of MILLISECONDS since Jan 1st, 1970.  So yes it is the Unix timestamp... in milliseconds.

Comment: Do you mean "Unix time stamp is in seconds"? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Unix time is number of seconds that have elapsed since midnight 1st January 1970 (UTC).

Comment: @ThomasReggi getTime() gives you the Unix timestamp in milliseconds.

Answer (score -1):

You are giving two different times to Date() and both of them are incorrect. Javascript's Date object accepts no argument for current time or milliseconds or date string or [year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds].

"Fri Jan 16 1970 10:43:09 GMT-0500 (EST)" is invalid format for Date(). For correct DateString formats check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: *"Javascript's Date object accepts no argument for current time or milliseconds or date string or [year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds]"* Sure it does: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2 You're quite right that that date format isn't valid **unless** it's what `toString` returns on a `Date` object on the implementation he/she is using. (An implementation is required to support parsing the format it produces, whatever that is, in addition to the simplified ISO-8601 added by ES5.)